# Formatting to three decimal on system.print with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, format, decimal

Trying to format so that my values from the xValue and yValue arrays appear with three decimal places. This is my attempt although java seems to not be accepting it :(

```
    double[] xValues = new double[arrayAmount];
    double[] yValues = new double[arrayAmount];

    xValues[0] = minimumValue;

    System.out.println("Values");
           for (int index = 0; index<arrayAmount; index++)
    {

        yValues[index] = 20.0 * Math.abs((Math.sin(xValues[index])));

System.out.printf("x: " + (%1.3f, xValues[index]) + "," + "y: " + (%1.3f, yValues[index]); // compiler error


        xValues[index+1] = xValues[index] + increment;



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) expects a `String` as its first argument, your current argument is a badly formed expression. You could do

```
System.out.printf("x: %1.3f, y: %1.3f%n",  xValues[index], yValues[index]);
```

Comment: @remimeus thank you! i did not know that. Although now all the X and Y values are printing on one line. Is there some way to Make it a printlnf somehow. So In one line x and y value appear, then the loop goes through and the next line down the next x and y value appear. Sorry if im confusing.

Comment: Read the [documentation for `Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) - to insert a newline simply use `%n` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.format` as suggested by @Reimeus or you can use a [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

```
final MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat("x: {0,number,0.00}, y: {1,number,0.00}");
```

Usage would be:

```
System.out.println(mf.format(new Object[]{xValues[index], yValues[index]}));
```